# Do all persistent Http request sent from client get routed to same pod in kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

In kubernetes, when we have multiple pods for service do all the http requests from a client gets routed to same pod?

If above is true, what happens when pod is processing(something like a large file upload in chunks) the request and pod goes down. Does the request fail

Comment: @hitshi by default when you connect to a service you get redirected to the pods in a round robing, kubernetes uses iptables to do this round roubing, so this mean, if you are doing a file upload, you will stay using the same tcp connection and you will stay in same pod

Comment: @c4f4t0r So what happens when client is sending the nth chunk and the pod goes down? I'm asking this because I may want to use the volume to append the chunks

Comment: if you are connected to a pod and this pod goes down, your tcp connection will be broken and you will go to a new pod when you will reconnect, you can try this by yourself killing a pod

Answer (score 0):

To summarize:

Kubernetes uses a feature called kube-proxy to handle the virtual IPs for services. Kubernetes allocates tasks to pods within a service by the round-robin method

With round-robin allocation, the system maintains a list of destinations. When a request comes in, it assigns the request to the next destination on the list, then permutes the list (either by simple rotation, or a more complex method), so the next request goes to the following destination on the list.

@c4f4t0r is absolutely right that once you start a file upload session - you will use the same pod and connection. In case something will happen with current connectivity(pod down) - the next session will be established with the next in round robin pod.